# Array loop inside conditional statement react-native not working

Tags: arrays, react-native, conditional-statements

I was trying to implement array iteration inside a conditional statement in react native like this,

```
{!loading&&documents.length>0?(
   {documents.map((item, i) => {
    return (
    <ViewButton>mybutton</ViewButton>
    )}}

   ):(
   null
 )}
```

But it shows syntax error in console

> Unexpected token, expected "," (43:21)
>
> 41 |            42 |
>   {!loading&&documents.length>0?(
>
> > 43 |            {documents.map((item, i) => {
> >          |                      ^   44 |             return (   45 |             sss   46 |             )}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax issue, this should work:

```
  !loading && documents.length > 0
? documents.map((item, i) => {
    return <ViewButton>mybutton</ViewButton>;
  })
: null;
```

I'd highly recommend to use a linter ([eslint](https://eslint.org/)) and something like [prettier](https://prettier.io/) so you don't run in issues like these.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  {!loading&&documents.length>0?(
   documents.map((item, i) => {
    return (
    <ViewButton>mybutton</ViewButton>
    )}

   )):(
   null
 )}
  }
```